# libcurl based ftp client program tls session getting timeout to vsftpd server. however curl works fine on same server port

Tags: ssl, libcurl, vsftpd

A ftp client program using `libcurl` is getting timeout. however curl work fine to same server port running `vsftpd` server.
Inside packet capture, difference i see that ftp client not getting `new session ticket` . seems like that client is waiting for that and getting timeout.

ftp client program packet capture[image]

curl packet capture(which work fine)
[image]

please help in finding out cause of the issue. trying this past two days no progress.

NOTE: server is same in both cases, there is just server interfaces ip difference, which appear in packet captures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be seen that the client is closing the connection 4 seconds after receiving application data from the server. The SSL handshake is finished at this stage already, so this is not a SSL problem.  Session Ticket is not important here but maybe the client simply did not announce support for it. Its likely a problem in your (unknown) code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for comment. my doubt is. is new session ticket not needed ? i feel like libcurl is waiting for that packet only. thats why when timeout happen it closes with encrypted alert.
shared client ssl code work fine for https, smtps requests. seeing this on ftps requests only. ftp also work fine.

Comment: The encrypted alert is likely a normal SSL shutdown, i.e. nothing special. And the SSL handshake completed successfully, no new session ticket is needed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich why it don't need new session ticket since i don't see session reuse or anything else.

Comment: and how you are sure ssl handshake is complete ?

Comment: Since application data are delivered inside the connection. These are only delivered once the handshake is complete. That's how TLS works.